# Ubuntu 16.04 laptop hanging, requires powercycle

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, crash, gnome, ubuntu-16.04

I'm seeing a weird situation where my new Dell Inspiron laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 is unpredictably hanging, and I can't seem to figure out why.  I haven't observed any consistent behaviour that causes it.  What happens is the windowing system (using Gnome) freezes, no mouse action, no response from keyboard, can't drop to shell, etc... so I have no choice but to do a hard powercycle to bring it back up.

The only kind of consistency I've observed so far is that this seems to always happen either when the screen is locked, and I move the mouse, or soon (<30 seconds) after unlocking the screen.

When I look through the syslog for possible problems, sometimes I see warnings, but those warnings also occur when the machine is NOT then locking up.   See below for the section from my syslog for the time immediately preceding the most recent time this has happened.  However, this section of log is before I actually unlocked the screen and encountered the hanging behaviour.  At the time of the actual problem there is nothing at all in the logs.

I am an experienced sysadmin, but new to running Ubuntu on a laptop, and this problem is frustrating my attempts to figure out what's going wrong.

I'm hoping someone can help me track down what is going wrong.

```
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664099] ------------[ cut here ]------------
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664187] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1468 at /build/linux-FvcHlK/linux-4.4.0/ubuntu/i915/intel_pm.c:3572 skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]()
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664193] WARN_ON(!wm_changed)
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664198] Modules linked in: drbg ansi_cprng ctr ccm ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 rfcomm iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 xt_addrtype iptable_filter ip_tables xt_conntrack x_tables nf_nat nf_conntrack br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs bnep arc4 iwlmvm mac80211 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core intel_rapl snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp btusb hid_sensor_rotation x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_core btrtl iwlwifi intel_powerclamp kvm_intel snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_compress hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d hid_sensor_gyro_3d ac97_bus snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_pcm_dmaengine hid_sensor_accel_3d snd_hda_codec_generic hid_sensor_als dw_dmac_core hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer hid_sensor_iio_common joydev snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec cfg80211 kvm snd_hda_core hid_multitouch snd_hwdep i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core snd_pcm dell_wmi sparse_keymap snd_seq_midi dell_laptop irqbypass snd_seq_midi_event dcdbas snd_rawmidi crct10dif_pclmul dell_smm_hwmon snd_seq crc32_pclmul snd_seq_device snd_timer aesni_intel hci_uart aes_x86_64 snd lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper btbcm cryptd btqca idma64 btintel mei_me soundcore virt_dma processor_thermal_device bluetooth mei intel_soc_dts_iosf shpchp intel_lpss_pci input_leds serio_raw soc_button_array acpi_als dell_smo8800 intel_lpss_acpi int3403_thermal int3402_thermal intel_lpss int340x_thermal_zone kfifo_buf int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel industrialio tpm_crb acpi_pad mac_hid uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media coretemp parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub hid_generic usbhid i915_bpo intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper psmouse syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ahci drm libahci i2c_hid wmi hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint video pinctrl_intel fjes
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664475] CPU: 0 PID: 1468 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W       4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664481] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 13-7359/03DMWJ, BIOS 01.00.00 08/07/2015
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664487]  0000000000000286 00000000c5fb32c1 ffff8802625d7938 ffffffff813e9c53
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664497]  ffff8802625d7980 ffffffffc0261c70 ffff8802625d7970 ffffffff81080fb2
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664505]  ffff8802686a3000 ffff880262a89d9c ffff8802686a4000 ffff8802630a6378
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664515] Call Trace:
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664553]  [<ffffffff813e9c53>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664566]  [<ffffffff81080fb2>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664575]  [<ffffffff8108104c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664641]  [<ffffffffc01935cc>] skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664702]  [<ffffffffc0193766>] skl_update_wm+0x186/0x5f0 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664794]  [<ffffffffc021f36f>] ? intel_ddi_enable_transcoder_func+0x17f/0x260 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664856]  [<ffffffffc019748e>] intel_update_watermarks+0x1e/0x30 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.664942]  [<ffffffffc0203401>] haswell_crtc_enable+0x321/0x8c0 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.665027]  [<ffffffffc01ffdad>] intel_atomic_commit+0x5dd/0xdb0 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.665095]  [<ffffffffc00a080e>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.665149]  [<ffffffffc00a0c47>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.665178]  [<ffffffffc014b9f6>] drm_atomic_helper_set_config+0x76/0xb0 [drm_kms_helper]
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.665230]  [<ffffffffc008fe02>] drm_mode_set_config_internal+0x62/0x100 [drm]
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.665283]  [<ffffffffc0094322>] drm_mode_setcrtc+0x3d2/0x4f0 [drm]
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.665329]  [<ffffffffc0085712>] drm_ioctl+0x152/0x540 [drm]
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.665393]  [<ffffffffc0093f50>] ? drm_mode_setplane+0x1b0/0x1b0 [drm]
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.665410]  [<ffffffff8122026f>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.665429]  [<ffffffff8108e0e1>] ? __set_task_blocked+0x41/0xa0
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.665444]  [<ffffffff81090a76>] ? __set_current_blocked+0x36/0x60
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.665456]  [<ffffffff812204d9>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.665468]  [<ffffffff81090d2e>] ? SyS_rt_sigprocmask+0x8e/0xc0
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.665487]  [<ffffffff818252f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
May 25 11:40:22 femur kernel: [95510.665497] ---[ end trace ac8303024c336b3e ]---
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792204] ------------[ cut here ]------------
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792284] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1468 at /build/linux-FvcHlK/linux-4.4.0/ubuntu/i915/intel_pm.c:3572 skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]()
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792289] WARN_ON(!wm_changed)
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792294] Modules linked in: drbg ansi_cprng ctr ccm ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 rfcomm iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 xt_addrtype iptable_filter ip_tables xt_conntrack x_tables nf_nat nf_conntrack br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs bnep arc4 iwlmvm mac80211 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core intel_rapl snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp btusb hid_sensor_rotation x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_core btrtl iwlwifi intel_powerclamp kvm_intel snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_compress hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d hid_sensor_gyro_3d ac97_bus snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_pcm_dmaengine hid_sensor_accel_3d snd_hda_codec_generic hid_sensor_als dw_dmac_core hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer hid_sensor_iio_common joydev snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec cfg80211 kvm snd_hda_core hid_multitouch snd_hwdep i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core snd_pcm dell_wmi sparse_keymap snd_seq_midi dell_laptop irqbypass snd_seq_midi_event dcdbas snd_rawmidi crct10dif_pclmul dell_smm_hwmon snd_seq crc32_pclmul snd_seq_device snd_timer aesni_intel hci_uart aes_x86_64 snd lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper btbcm cryptd btqca idma64 btintel mei_me soundcore virt_dma processor_thermal_device bluetooth mei intel_soc_dts_iosf shpchp intel_lpss_pci input_leds serio_raw soc_button_array acpi_als dell_smo8800 intel_lpss_acpi int3403_thermal int3402_thermal intel_lpss int340x_thermal_zone kfifo_buf int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel industrialio tpm_crb acpi_pad mac_hid uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media coretemp parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub hid_generic usbhid i915_bpo intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper psmouse syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ahci drm libahci i2c_hid wmi hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint video pinctrl_intel fjes
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792626] CPU: 0 PID: 1468 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W       4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792634] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 13-7359/03DMWJ, BIOS 01.00.00 08/07/2015
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792641]  0000000000000286 00000000c5fb32c1 ffff8802625d79d0 ffffffff813e9c53
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792654]  ffff8802625d7a18 ffffffffc0261c70 ffff8802625d7a08 ffffffff81080fb2
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792666]  ffff8802686a4000 ffff880262a89d9c ffff8802686a3000 ffff8802630a6378
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792677] Call Trace:
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792698]  [<ffffffff813e9c53>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792731]  [<ffffffff81080fb2>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792744]  [<ffffffff8108104c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792830]  [<ffffffffc01935cc>] skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792914]  [<ffffffffc0193766>] skl_update_wm+0x186/0x5f0 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.792998]  [<ffffffffc019748e>] intel_update_watermarks+0x1e/0x30 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793121]  [<ffffffffc01ffc36>] intel_atomic_commit+0x466/0xdb0 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793207]  [<ffffffffc00a080e>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793275]  [<ffffffffc00a0c47>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793313]  [<ffffffffc014a14d>] drm_atomic_helper_connector_dpms+0xed/0x1a0 [drm_kms_helper]
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793389]  [<ffffffffc009527c>] drm_mode_obj_set_property_ioctl+0x25c/0x270 [drm]
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793453]  [<ffffffffc00952cf>] drm_mode_connector_property_set_ioctl+0x3f/0x60 [drm]
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793505]  [<ffffffffc0085712>] drm_ioctl+0x152/0x540 [drm]
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793564]  [<ffffffffc0095290>] ? drm_mode_obj_set_property_ioctl+0x270/0x270 [drm]
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793579]  [<ffffffff812239bf>] ? dput+0x2f/0x220
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793591]  [<ffffffff8122d1e4>] ? mntput+0x24/0x40
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793602]  [<ffffffff8122026f>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793617]  [<ffffffff8120e7fe>] ? ____fput+0xe/0x10
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793632]  [<ffffffff8109e9a8>] ? task_work_run+0x78/0x90
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793641]  [<ffffffff812204d9>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793659]  [<ffffffff818252f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
May 25 11:40:46 femur kernel: [95534.793668] ---[ end trace ac8303024c336b3f ]---
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.929604] ------------[ cut here ]------------
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.929680] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1468 at /build/linux-FvcHlK/linux-4.4.0/ubuntu/i915/intel_pm.c:3572 skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]()
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.929685] WARN_ON(!wm_changed)
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.929690] Modules linked in: drbg ansi_cprng ctr ccm ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 rfcomm iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 xt_addrtype iptable_filter ip_tables xt_conntrack x_tables nf_nat nf_conntrack br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs bnep arc4 iwlmvm mac80211 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core intel_rapl snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp btusb hid_sensor_rotation x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_core btrtl iwlwifi intel_powerclamp kvm_intel snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_compress hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d hid_sensor_gyro_3d ac97_bus snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_pcm_dmaengine hid_sensor_accel_3d snd_hda_codec_generic hid_sensor_als dw_dmac_core hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer hid_sensor_iio_common joydev snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec cfg80211 kvm snd_hda_core hid_multitouch snd_hwdep i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core snd_pcm dell_wmi sparse_keymap snd_seq_midi dell_laptop irqbypass snd_seq_midi_event dcdbas snd_rawmidi crct10dif_pclmul dell_smm_hwmon snd_seq crc32_pclmul snd_seq_device snd_timer aesni_intel hci_uart aes_x86_64 snd lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper btbcm cryptd btqca idma64 btintel mei_me soundcore virt_dma processor_thermal_device bluetooth mei intel_soc_dts_iosf shpchp intel_lpss_pci input_leds serio_raw soc_button_array acpi_als dell_smo8800 intel_lpss_acpi int3403_thermal int3402_thermal intel_lpss int340x_thermal_zone kfifo_buf int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel industrialio tpm_crb acpi_pad mac_hid uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media coretemp parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub hid_generic usbhid i915_bpo intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper psmouse syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ahci drm libahci i2c_hid wmi hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint video pinctrl_intel fjes
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.929967] CPU: 0 PID: 1468 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W       4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.929972] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 13-7359/03DMWJ, BIOS 01.00.00 08/07/2015
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.929977]  0000000000000286 00000000c5fb32c1 ffff8802625d7938 ffffffff813e9c53
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.929988]  ffff8802625d7980 ffffffffc0261c70 ffff8802625d7970 ffffffff81080fb2
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.929996]  ffff8802686a3000 ffff880262a89d9c ffff8802686a4000 ffff8802630a6378
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930006] Call Trace:
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930057]  [<ffffffff813e9c53>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930069]  [<ffffffff81080fb2>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930079]  [<ffffffff8108104c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930137]  [<ffffffffc01935cc>] skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930194]  [<ffffffffc0193766>] skl_update_wm+0x186/0x5f0 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930283]  [<ffffffffc021f36f>] ? intel_ddi_enable_transcoder_func+0x17f/0x260 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930339]  [<ffffffffc019748e>] intel_update_watermarks+0x1e/0x30 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930422]  [<ffffffffc0203401>] haswell_crtc_enable+0x321/0x8c0 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930504]  [<ffffffffc01ffdad>] intel_atomic_commit+0x5dd/0xdb0 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930568]  [<ffffffffc00a080e>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930621]  [<ffffffffc00a0c47>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930650]  [<ffffffffc014b9f6>] drm_atomic_helper_set_config+0x76/0xb0 [drm_kms_helper]
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930698]  [<ffffffffc008fe02>] drm_mode_set_config_internal+0x62/0x100 [drm]
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930747]  [<ffffffffc0094322>] drm_mode_setcrtc+0x3d2/0x4f0 [drm]
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930783]  [<ffffffffc0085712>] drm_ioctl+0x152/0x540 [drm]
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930826]  [<ffffffffc0093f50>] ? drm_mode_setplane+0x1b0/0x1b0 [drm]
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930837]  [<ffffffff8122026f>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930848]  [<ffffffff8108e0e1>] ? __set_task_blocked+0x41/0xa0
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930858]  [<ffffffff81090a76>] ? __set_current_blocked+0x36/0x60
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930866]  [<ffffffff812204d9>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930875]  [<ffffffff81090d2e>] ? SyS_rt_sigprocmask+0x8e/0xc0
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930889]  [<ffffffff818252f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
May 25 11:41:26 femur kernel: [95573.930905] ---[ end trace ac8303024c336b40 ]---
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795148] ------------[ cut here ]------------
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795263] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1468 at /build/linux-FvcHlK/linux-4.4.0/ubuntu/i915/intel_pm.c:3572 skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]()
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795269] WARN_ON(!wm_changed)
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795274] Modules linked in: drbg ansi_cprng ctr ccm ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 rfcomm iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 xt_addrtype iptable_filter ip_tables xt_conntrack x_tables nf_nat nf_conntrack br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs bnep arc4 iwlmvm mac80211 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core intel_rapl snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp btusb hid_sensor_rotation x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_core btrtl iwlwifi intel_powerclamp kvm_intel snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_compress hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d hid_sensor_gyro_3d ac97_bus snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_pcm_dmaengine hid_sensor_accel_3d snd_hda_codec_generic hid_sensor_als dw_dmac_core hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer hid_sensor_iio_common joydev snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec cfg80211 kvm snd_hda_core hid_multitouch snd_hwdep i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core snd_pcm dell_wmi sparse_keymap snd_seq_midi dell_laptop irqbypass snd_seq_midi_event dcdbas snd_rawmidi crct10dif_pclmul dell_smm_hwmon snd_seq crc32_pclmul snd_seq_device snd_timer aesni_intel hci_uart aes_x86_64 snd lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper btbcm cryptd btqca idma64 btintel mei_me soundcore virt_dma processor_thermal_device bluetooth mei intel_soc_dts_iosf shpchp intel_lpss_pci input_leds serio_raw soc_button_array acpi_als dell_smo8800 intel_lpss_acpi int3403_thermal int3402_thermal intel_lpss int340x_thermal_zone kfifo_buf int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel industrialio tpm_crb acpi_pad mac_hid uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media coretemp parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub hid_generic usbhid i915_bpo intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper psmouse syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ahci drm libahci i2c_hid wmi hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint video pinctrl_intel fjes
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795552] CPU: 0 PID: 1468 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W       4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795557] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 13-7359/03DMWJ, BIOS 01.00.00 08/07/2015
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795563]  0000000000000286 00000000c5fb32c1 ffff8802625d79d0 ffffffff813e9c53
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795573]  ffff8802625d7a18 ffffffffc0261c70 ffff8802625d7a08 ffffffff81080fb2
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795582]  ffff8802686a4000 ffff880262a89d9c ffff8802686a3000 ffff8802630a6378
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795590] Call Trace:
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795608]  [<ffffffff813e9c53>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795621]  [<ffffffff81080fb2>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795630]  [<ffffffff8108104c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795696]  [<ffffffffc01935cc>] skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795758]  [<ffffffffc0193766>] skl_update_wm+0x186/0x5f0 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795818]  [<ffffffffc019748e>] intel_update_watermarks+0x1e/0x30 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795907]  [<ffffffffc01ffc36>] intel_atomic_commit+0x466/0xdb0 [i915_bpo]
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.795976]  [<ffffffffc00a080e>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.796031]  [<ffffffffc00a0c47>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.796062]  [<ffffffffc014a14d>] drm_atomic_helper_connector_dpms+0xed/0x1a0 [drm_kms_helper]
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.796118]  [<ffffffffc009527c>] drm_mode_obj_set_property_ioctl+0x25c/0x270 [drm]
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.796165]  [<ffffffffc00952cf>] drm_mode_connector_property_set_ioctl+0x3f/0x60 [drm]
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.796203]  [<ffffffffc0085712>] drm_ioctl+0x152/0x540 [drm]
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.796244]  [<ffffffffc0095290>] ? drm_mode_obj_set_property_ioctl+0x270/0x270 [drm]
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.796255]  [<ffffffff812239bf>] ? dput+0x2f/0x220
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.796264]  [<ffffffff8122d1e4>] ? mntput+0x24/0x40
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.796272]  [<ffffffff8122026f>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.796284]  [<ffffffff8120e7fe>] ? ____fput+0xe/0x10
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.796296]  [<ffffffff8109e9a8>] ? task_work_run+0x78/0x90
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.796304]  [<ffffffff812204d9>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.796318]  [<ffffffff818252f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
May 25 11:41:51 femur kernel: [95599.796324] ---[ end trace ac8303024c336b41 ]---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very likely hardware issue.

I had similar problems twice with new hardware, once with new motherboard and once with new laptop. When you buy new hardware you expect it to fly, and when it starts freezing - after 4th or 5th reboot you can be ready to throw it through the window. :)

Motherboard problem was solved with new BIOS firmware, laptop problem was solved in service with change of faulty memory.

If you have time and energy, and spare partition on hard disk (or spare external drive), you can try installing Windows, as problem may be in drivers, it does not need to be faulty hardware.

If Windows are working OK after two or three days, than you can try to disable in BIOS hardware which can be disabled (like graphic card), and you can try using other kernel version (newer or older), or disable some drivers.

I'm aware that such tasks are complicated, but deducing/debugging hardware problems is job for experienced users or professionals.

*Edit:* Recent Dell laptops are quite Linux friendly (they even had series of XPS's or Inspirons labeled Linux inside or something like that), so recent kernel & distribution (Ubuntu 1604 was published last month) and fresh install should work without problems. I know this is not information that you are happy to read, but as unlikely it can seem (faulty new hardware), it is possibility which should not be discarded without thought.

I write this not to scare you, but to hasten solving of your problem, as I quite well remember how I miserably felt when I was in similar situation.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't sound too good.  Well, I finally just managed to get the BIOS and firmwares upgraded to the most recent (25-Apr-2016) version available.  I guess I'll have to see if that makes a difference, but I have to admit I'm not holding out all that much hope of it fixing the problem, unfortunately.

Thanks for your hints, and I'll update this superuser.com post with the outcome, whatever it ends up being!

Comment: Looking good! I haven't suffered the hanging problem since upgrading the laptop's BIOS! Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I'm really pleased to hear it, as I estimated that old firmware/faulty hardware  possibility was ~80%/20%, but if second revealed true no positive estimation would do you any good, so I did not share that earlier.

Now you know, sometimes MB manufacturer ships hardware with old firmware (or rather, MB are on storage long enough for firmware to become old and not compatible with newer memory type) and to get it working properly, you need to flash BIOS.
You would expect that Dell would do that for you, but evidently that is not always the case. I'm really glad to hear positive feedback!

Comment: @RossMessiah I am running into the same issue with my Dell Precission 5510. I lock the screen, come back and I have to do a powercycle. I am on the latest bios version and I was wondering if the BISO change fixed it for you or you did something else additionally? I am seeing the same message in syslog..

Comment: Heya pandaadb!  Yeah, the BIOS update seems to have totally fixed it.  I haven't had any re-occurrences of the freezing problem since updating the BIOS.  Hopefully it will work for you, too!

Comment: I worked out that this only happens when the computer is locked, so i think it might be a different issue. For now, i disabled locking and keep my eyes open for new updates. Thanks!